# In the New Google Maps, How do I Highlight Several Addresses at Once?

Tags: google-maps

In classic Google Maps, I used to be able to show several placemarks at a time. I used this a lot to find hotels or other places of interest near a location I know I would have to go to.

The following was my procedure to do so:

- Enter 1st address in search bar, hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.
- Enter 2nd address in search bar, hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.
- ...
- Enter nth address in search bar, hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.
- The popup menu where you could enable/disable transit and traffic info contained a history of all most recently searched for addresses. Enable all those addresses.
- Each of the addresses is shown with a differently coloured placemark.
- Zoom out far enough so all placemarks are visible in the map at once.

**How can I achieve this in the new Google Maps?**

Once I search for a 2nd address, I do not seem to have any way to also still show the first address I displayed before.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the top left corner of Google Maps, click "Save" with the star over it.

Comment: I only see the *Directions* icon there. How do I get the *Save* one?